# Flutter how to create message real-time and notifications

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am a web developer and I am planning to create my first Windows application using Flutter.
I have learned the basics and I understand Dart development. However, I am a novice in application development for how to implement my project with real-time updates and notifications.
I want to develop an internal project tracking application in the style of Discord, namely:

- Channels that will concern current projects
- Messages associated with each channel with interaction to indicate who is responsible for this modification

I had the idea of creating files with separators to be able to read and loop:
File "Channel" channel_name;number_of_messages_unprocessed
File "channel_name" text;interaction

I think I will make an API to update the files on the server.

My questions:

- How to update the information without refreshing the application?
- I also want to send a notification to each person who has requested to follow the messages of a specific Channel
- I prefer to use free modules as much as possible without having to pay for this application

Flutter modules:

- "http" to retrieve files from my server
- "flutter_local_notifications" can it allow me to send a notification without going through Firebase?

I created a page in "StatefulWidget" to retrieve my "Salon" file for display. This is working fine, but if I modify the file on the server, I only see the update if I restart the application.

I am open to suggestions.
Thank you in advance.